# How to register many object as beans in Spring Java Config?

Tags: spring, spring-java-config

I would like dynamically register multiple objects as Spring beans. Is is possible, without `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`?

```
@Configuration public class MyConfig {

    @Bean A single() { return new A("X");}

    @Bean List<A> many() { return Arrays.asList(new A("Y"), new A("Z"));}

    private static class A {

        private String name;

        public A(String name) { this.name = name;}

        @PostConstruct public void print() {
            System.err.println(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Actual output shows only one bean is working:

> X

Expected:

> X Y Z

Spring 4.3.2.RELEASE

Comment: Actually you have 2 beans... One bean named `single` of type `A` and one bean named `many` of type `List`. Your internal ones (the ones in the list) aren't beans nor managed by Spring. What you want cannot be done out-of-the-box.

Comment: @M.Deinum, thanks. Any hint how to get it beyond-the-box?

Comment: What would it add. In the sample it would add nothing but complexity as you now have added another way of adding beans. You still need to constrcuct them. If you want to add beans either use a `FactoryBean` or create your own `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` or `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` to add the definitions of your beans.

Comment: @M.Deinum, unfortunately `FactoryBean` creates a single beans but I want many. `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` works with `BeanDefinition` but I need to work with concrete objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify your `A` bean definition kind of prototype with a parameter

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    A template(String seed) {
        return new A(seed);
    }

    @Bean
    String singleA() {
        return "X";
    }

    @Bean
    List<A> many() {
        return asList(template("Y"), template("Z"));
    }

    private static class A {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfig.class);
        A a = (A) context.getBean("template");
        System.out.println(a);
        List<A> l = (List<A>) context.getBean("many");
        System.out.println(l);
    }
}
```

`prototype` scope allows Spring to create a new `A` with every `template` execution and register an instance into context.

The result of `main` execution is as you expect

```
Y
Z
MyConfig$A@15bfd87
[MyConfig$A@543e710e, MyConfig$A@57f23557]
X
```

Comment: Prototype, excellent idea! I modified answer a bit, because `List` is unnecessary. All I wanted was 3 beans in context, 1 declared explicite, 2 declared dynamically

Comment: Prototype is not as excellent as I though. The problem is that when prototype is created, it cannot be reinjected in other places (in other words, cannot be loaded by ApplicationContext.getBeanOfType(A.class))

Answer (score 0):

What I want is impossible but requested with https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13348

If you think multiple bean registration is OK please upvote