# Spring Java Config - Is it possible to create a @Bean dinamically?

Tags: spring, spring-java-config

Given this configuration class, I want to dinamically create a `DataSourceTransactionManager` bean for each one of the DataSource objects, is it possible?

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource[] dataSources;

}
```

That is to say, I want to loop the dataSources array to create a `@Bean` that returns a `new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource[i])`.

In this case I don't want to create a `@Bean List<DataSourceTransactionManager>` as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39510702/how-to-register-many-object-as-beans-in-spring-java-config), but a number of `@Bean DataSourceTransactionManager` instances.

Comment: Not like this. You could create a `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` which gets all `BeanDefinitions` for a `DataSource` bean and adds additional `BeanDefinitions` for the `DataSourceTransactionManager`s.

Comment: I had already considered that but I was looking for a more "friendly" way of doing it directly in Spring Java Config instead of messing with BeanDefinitions

Comment: Well you cannot you have to create additional definitions yourself. However how are you going to use them. You still need to explicitly define which transaction manager to use in `@Transactional` else it will not work. So not sure what you are trying to achieve but still it looks like part of the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to register many object as beans in Spring Java Config?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39510702/how-to-register-many-object-as-beans-in-spring-java-config)